# Cannot access memory at address with strtok()

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, strtok

i'm learning C, and i need to build code to read and compare users logins from CSV file. I'm trying separate the CSV values in array using `strtok()`function. But when i debug the code (With Visual Studio Code) it show me the error `Cannot access memory at address` at line of `user_data_column = strtok(line, ',');`. I don't found search results so that specific case, but within sucess. The complete code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
    
char username[50], password[50];
char cwd[PATH_MAX];
void show_login()
{
    typedef struct
    {
        char *user;
        char *password;
    } * user;

    char *user_data_column;
    user *user_data;

    getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd));
    strcat(cwd, "/data/Users.csv");

    FILE *users_list = fopen(cwd, "r");
    long file_length = ftell(users_list);
    char *buffer = malloc(file_length);
    char line[PATH_MAX];
    int line_counter = 0;
    int is_authorized = 0;

    printf("\bLogin\n");
    printf("Nome do usuário: ");
    fgets(username, sizeof(username), stdin);
    printf("Senha: ");
    fgets(password, sizeof(password), stdin);

    if (users_list)
    {
        if (buffer)
        {
            while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), users_list) != NULL)
            {
                if (line_counter == 0)
                {
                    line_counter++;

                    continue;
                }
                user_data_column = strtok(line, ',');
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Erro! O arquivo Users.csv não foi encontrado\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(users_list);
}

int main()
{
    show_login();
    return 0;
}
```

(The step of compare login isn't done)
Error:

[image]

Comment: The second argument to `strtok()` should be a string, not a `char`.

Comment: `strtok(line, ",")`

Comment: You should have gotten a warning about the type mismatch when compiling.

Comment: The `user` typedef probably shouldn't be a pointer.

Comment: Also note if you are calling `strtok()` more than once on the same string, only the FIRST call uses `strtok(line, ...;` all subsequent calls to obtain the second token on, uses `strtok (NULL, ...`.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing with single quote, use double quotes in the second parameter.

```
  strtok(line, ",");
```